# Convert string array to char **

Tags: c++

For example:

```
string str[3];
void foo(char** str)
{
  //do something to str...
}
```

How to pass str[] to function foo in a convenient way?

Comment: is there even such a thing like `char**`? Shouldn't it be `char[]*`?

Comment: Make an array of `char *`s, copy the strings (I'm assuming that the lack of `const` means it modifies them), and pass that in.

Comment: @texasbruce - Yes there is - you can even have `char ********** str` if you so desire.

Comment: @EdHeal -1, not enough stars.

Comment: There were many discussions on `char**` before. Of course you can have pointer to pointer, but pointer to char pointer as parameter is not practical.

Comment: @texasbruce, It kind of is to prevent guessing the maximum length without repercussions. The parameter using C strings and dynamic arrays is the annoying part.

Comment: @Borgleader - Why the -1? You can have a pointer to a pointer to a pointer ....

Comment: @EdHeal It was merely a joke, I actualy upvoted your comment. -.-;

Comment: @Borgleader - fine. cheers

Comment: No one try to solve this problem but to discuss `char **** s` is valid or not... I don't know, why this question is off-topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function expects an array of pointers, so you'll have to make one from your array of strings:

```
std::vector<char*> pointers;
for (auto & s : str) {
    pointers.push_back(&s[0]);
}
foo(&pointers[0]);
```

Beware that this may not be valid if the function modifies the pointers, or the strings they point to. A better option would be to avoid mixing C and C++ style string handling, if possible.

Comment: I heard somewhere that before C++11 there was no guarantee that string data was stored contiguously, but that no implementation fragmented string storage anyway, so they made it a requirement in C++11.